# running hello world - not getting hello world on screen

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Yeah so im making a bog standard Hello world to make sure android is working. Its my first time working with android so im setting up the enviornment. Ive made the program per: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

But when i run the program the emulator comes up with the time and date and that its charging. Nothing like the pic in the tutorial. Also the emulator is different though id assume thats cos i made the AVD Android 3.0. Anyone tell me what i need to do to just get Hello World to come up?

Answer (score 4):

It's probably just sitting at the lock screen. Just swipe across or down to unlock, and your app should show up.

Comment: Ah right. Well it was on the lock screen, but im still not seeing it. Im getting a search box for google. Ive looked on all the screens and gone to the My Apps link in the emulator. Cant find it. ALso the emulator is really slow, is that normal? i know its slow to load up but its very slow going from one screen to the next as well.

Comment: Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) emulator is known to be very slow. It's emulating the processor and doing all screen updates using the CPU, not the GPU. If you're just getting into it, I'd suggest using a lower SDK - like 2.2 or 2.3. That emulator is much quicker. You'll have to create a new AVD, targeting a lower platform.

Comment: Okay seems faster alright cheers. But im still not seeing Hello World anywhere. Anyone have any ideas whats going on?

Comment: The tutorial says i should get a black screen printing "Hello, Android" with a grey bit on top with the name of the program. But im getting the emulator. So basically what looks like the home page of a phone using Android 2.1, a google search bar, a few app shortcuts, etc. Anyone know what i might be doing wrong. As far as i can tell ive followed the instructions to the letter. Ive looked around the different pages as well and there's nothing on any of them.

Comment: Ok, now you have to look at the console output to make sure it is successfully installing the app (.apk file) onto the emulator. It should be saying something like "successfully installed", then "starting activity...."

Comment: where is the console output? I could of sworn i got build information on the bottom (similar to visual studio) but that isnt there any more. I get windows that open but not for long enough to read what they saying.

Comment: And the console window has magically re-appeared. Anyway, here is what i get when i run the program: [2011-02-24 19:16:31 - HelloWorld] ---------------------------- [2011-02-24 19:16:31 - HelloWorld] Android Launch! [2011-02-24 19:16:31 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally. [2011-02-24 19:16:31 - HelloWorld] Performing com.example.helloworld.HelloWorld activity launch [2011-02-24 19:16:31 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD '2.1AVD' [2011-02-24 19:16:31 - HelloWorld] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device '2.1AVD (cant format this sorry)

Comment: Im not getting anything like what you mention John. seems the program isnt trying to install the app onto the emulator. any idea why this would happen?

Comment: What do you have in your manifest file, specifically which sdk are you targeting? Specifically the android:minSdkVersion and android:targetSdkVersion. Make sure they match the avd you are trying to launch, etc.

Comment: I set the build target to be 2.1 as in the tutorial above. Just after noticing, i thought the min sdk field was left alone cos it doesnt mention it in the text, but it has 7. But when i put 7 in there im getting an error when i compile:

Comment: [2011-02-24 20:34:31 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first
[2011-02-24 20:34:31 - HelloAndroids] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first
[2011-02-24 20:35:59 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first
[2011-02-24 20:35:59 - HelloAndroids] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first

Comment: So restarting Eclipse somehow fixed that. Though every time now the emulator brings up and error asking do i want to force close or wait. Seems okay if i choose to wait. But still no app. Im pissed off with it now. Gonna leave it till tomorrow. Cheers for the help so far.

Comment: @Conor did you get this fixed? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this also, which led me to this thread.

I left the SDK version field to be blank.

```
[2011-06-01 21:46:23 - helloWorld] Uploading helloWorld.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-06-01 21:46:23 - helloWorld] Installing helloWorld.apk...
[2011-06-01 21:46:45 - helloWorld] Success!
[2011-06-01 21:46:45 - helloWorld] Starting activity com.myhelloworld.MainAct on device emulator-5554
[2011-06-01 21:46:49 - helloWorld] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.myhelloworld/.MainAct }
[2011-06-01 21:47:47 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentred
[2011-06-01 21:47:47 - Emulator]
```

After this message, I wait for the emulator to boot up and i unlocked it and saw its home screen. After a couple of seconds later, my app showed up.

Answer (score 1):

Set options:

```
-noaudio -no-snapshot-load
```

in

```
Run->Run Configurations...->Target->Additional Emulator Command Line Options
```

For me it work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and the answer is here: [running hello world - not getting hello world on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106421/running-hello-world-not-getting-hello-world-on-screen)

You do have to wait a good while the first time you load up the AVD.  You do have to swipe or w/e to unlock it.  Hit the OK button if you see it.  Once you get to the "home page", click on the middle button on the bottom menu.  This will bring up the apps on the emulator.  Find your Hello, Android app, click on it, and you should see your Hello World.

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same issue, first time installed Android SDK+Eclipse and tried "Hello, World!", below are steps which helped me figure out what is going on (apologize if this could be worked around in much simple way).

By default when emulator is starting it show "A N D R O I D..." text with blinking cursor

1. Just wait a bit while it load completely
2. Press Unlock button at the Desctop Screen
3. When loaded drag to the right `"Unlock"` button (IMG1)

Also you can find and launch manually your application in the Applications list:

1. At the bottom of Android Desctop press `"Applications"` button (IMG2)
2. From a list of available applications select your application and double click to run

**IMG1: Unlock button**

[image: * UnLock button]

**IMG2: Applications button**

[image: ** Applications button]